# extract only index with the value of "date" from a JSON file with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

I am accessing a JSON file with nodejs api request.

the file file has 1000's of data.

var data = fileData[0].data has the "date" values in multiple objects. The objects have two values "date" and "value". I just want to print the "date" values of the whole data variable.

```
"idNumber": "98745973459479574935794577345",
    "data": [
        {
            "date": "2001-09-12T08:37:09.009Z",
            "value": 307479
        },
        {
            "date": "2001-09-12T08:36:53.919Z",
            "value": 307478
        },
        {
            "date": "2001-09-12T08:36:38.809Z",
            "value": 307477
        },
```

There are thousands of these objects within the array. I just want to print all the "date". I tried `console.log(data[0])` but it would print the first value and it will also include the "value" which I don't want.

is it possible to print every index with the keyword of "date"? If so, how?

Comment: If the forEach and map did not work for you, then you need to show more data and expexted output

Comment: Hi, I’ve solved this already. The answer is a little bit down on this page                                         var solution = data.map(function (date){
return date.date;
})

console.log(solution)

Comment: That is what [I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69150978/295783)!

Comment: Sorry sir, your code did not work in this situation. Maybe because the data is coming from an api. But this code worked; var solution = data.map(function (date){ return date.date; }) console.log(solution)

Comment: I will test your code again and let you know sir

Comment: `const solution = data.map(({date}) => date)`

Answer (score 0):

```
data.forEach(item=>{
console.log(item.date)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This did not give me the value of all the dates, just some of them

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate whole array in order to get the date value.

You can use for loop, while loop, foreach etc, to iterate.

For Each Loop:

```js
let data = [
        {
            "date": "2001-09-12T08:37:09.009Z",
            "value": 307479
        },
        {
            "date": "2001-09-12T08:36:53.919Z",
            "value": 307478
        },
        {
            "date": "2001-09-12T08:36:38.809Z",
            "value": 307477
        },
]

data.forEach(i => {
    console.log(i.date)
})
```

For Loop:

```js
    let data = [
            {
                "date": "2001-09-12T08:37:09.009Z",
                "value": 307479
            },
            {
                "date": "2001-09-12T08:36:53.919Z",
                "value": 307478
            },
            {
                "date": "2001-09-12T08:36:38.809Z",
                "value": 307477
            },
    ]

    
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        console.log(data[i].date)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Map seems to be a good method for you

NOTE I name the outer object `obj` so to get the data I use `obj.data`

```js
const obj = {
  "idNumber": "98745973459479574935794577345",
  "data": [{
      "date": "2001-09-12T08:37:09.009Z",
      "value": 307479
    },
    {
      "date": "2001-09-12T08:36:53.919Z",
      "value": 307478
    },
    {
      "date": "2001-09-12T08:36:38.809Z",
      "value": 307477
    }
  ]
}
console.log(obj.data.map(({date}) => date).join(','))
```

Comment: How is this an improvement of already posted answers?

Comment: Ok apologies if I got irritated when ppl post just to post. My comment to your answer was made when had ONLY posted a foreach example already posted. You have since added more code and description

Answer (score 0):

This code worked

```
var solution = data.map(function (date){
return date.date;
})

console.log(solution)
```